# 'Access is denied' error when calling CreateFile from a UMDF driver (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-7, driver, createfile, umdf

I am creating a UMDF driver which needs to change the brightness of the LCD back light.

The following line of code works in a Console App and successfully returns a handle to the device:

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\LCD", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

However, when I use the exact same piece of code in my driver it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError() gives code 5 which is 'Access is denied'

The driver is being debugged remotely on an x64 Windows 7 machine using the standard WDKRemoteUser profile.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Do I need to set permissions and, if so, how?

Comment: `CreateFile` is part of the Win32 API, how are you using that from a      driver?  Or are you really calling `ZwCreateFile`?

Comment: Hi BenJ! Is it just a case of me using an incorrect function then? I will give the ZwCreateFile a try :) Will I still be able to use DeviceIoControl() if I manage to obtain the handle, or is there a special driver function for that as well that I need to use?

Comment: Apologies, I haven't used UMDF, it looks as though using the Win32 API is completely fine in that environment.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you need to [impersonate the drivers client.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> UMDF drivers typically run under the LocalService account and cannot
>   access files or resources that require user credentials, such as
>   protected files or other protected resources. A UMDF driver typically
>   operates on commands and data that flow between a client application
>   and a device. Therefore, most UMDF drivers do not access protected
>   resources.
>
> The framework provides an impersonation capability that allows drivers
>   to impersonate the driver's client and obtain the client's access
>   rights to protected resources.